# mySQL count occurrences with JOIN (with date parameters)

Tags: mysql, join, count, conditional-statements, many-to-one

I asked a question here: [mySQL count occurrences with JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18101670/)

This question, asked how to count occurrences of a tag after joining etc.

I'd like to know how to do this, but also checking the event `publish_date` as I only want to include tags within the past 6 months or year.

```
**events** 
| id  |    publish_date   |
+-------------------------+
+ 1   | 1377612000        |
+ 2   | 1377612000        |
+ 3   | 1377612000        |

**Event_Categories** (Stores Tags / Categories)
| id  | name      |
+-----------------+
+ 1   | sport     |
+ 2   | charity   |
+ 3   | other_tag |


**Events_Categories** (Linking Table)
| event_id  | event_category_id |
+-------------------------------+
+    1      |       1           |   
+    2      |       2           |   
+    3      |       1           |   
+    3      |       2           |
```

**SQL which returns count of tags** (not taking into account the publish dates)SELECT c.name AS

```
tag_name, COUNT(ec.event_id) AS occurrences 
FROM Event_Categories c 
INNER JOIN Events_Categories ec ON c.id = ec.event_category_id 
GROUP BY c.id
```

Thanks! :)

Comment: I see no publish_date and no effort on your side.

Comment: publish_date would be on the events table, which is linked by Events_Categories, which shows holds event_id. I figured there was no need to display the events table, as only relevant fields are id & publish_date (unix time)

Comment: @juergend - Sorry that you feel this way, I asked on here and thought that I had provided all the information. Whilst asking this, I have been trying my own solution (see below)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.name AS tag_name, COUNT(ec.event_id) AS occurrences 
FROM event_categories c 
INNER JOIN events_categories ec ON c.id = ec.event_category_id 
JOIN events e ON e.id = ec.event_id
WHERE(e.publish_end_date > (unix_timestamp() -7889229) OR e.publish_end_date = 0)
GROUP BY c.id
```