# INNERJOIN WITH COUNT DISTINCT

Tags: php, mysql

I have to tables.

One form is called forms:

And this contains a field called 'instantie' which is a number

This refers to a table called instanties_cat. There the number is connected to a name

Now I would like to create the sum of each unique category name that is used in alle the forms.

So I quess an innerjoin with a distinct count ? But i can't seem to figure it out.

This is what I have so far, but if so far

```
global $conn;
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT COUNT(Instantie) as count FROM forms
        INNERJOIN instanties_cat
        ON forms.Instantie = instanties_cat.ID";

$query = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query))
{
  echo $result['Instantie'] . ' : ' . $result['count'] . ' keer.<br />';
}
```

What I would like have as a result is:

Biking: 1 keer
Cars : 3 keer
Walking: 12 keer

etc..

Table is called forms. Is has een ID, name, cat_id, and date.
Table 2 is called categories. Is has an ID and a catname.

So now I have many forms i want to find out per catname how many times they are in used in the forms.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [mySQL count occurrences with JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18101670/mysql-count-occurrences-with-join)

Comment: try add name of distict value, example: `SELECT forms.name_cat, DISTINCT COUNT(Instantie) as count FROM forms ....`

Comment: I keep getting back: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in D:\xampp\htdocs\kompas\functions.php on line.

Comment: It should be `INNER JOIN`, not `INNERJOIN` (blank in between), also get the SQL error message using `mysqli::error`

Comment: @dualed it says : Undefined index: Instantie

Comment: @BasSchreuder Not sure about that error message, but you should not `DISTINCT SELECT` but `GROUP BY Instantie` or [`COUNT(DISTINCT Instantie)`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_count) without more details I can't tell you more